# I'm trying to create command for special roles, but it doesn't work

Tags: python, discord.py

This command for users with specific roles.
It doesn't sand message, but also it doesn't sand message about error. Please help
My code:

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def m(ctx, *,message,amount = 1):
  if "Test" in [role.name for role in message.author.roles]:
    embed = discord.Embed(description=message, color = 0x1abc9c)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount)
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  else:
    print("error")
```

Comment: What's on the console? Any errors?

Comment: No, it doesn't send errors

Comment: @12944qwerty It is more like logical error. Many errors are not printed in the console while using this library.

Comment: @HackJonny It won't work at all. When you used `*, message` in the function, it measn that all the values after the `ctx` arguement are message. So adding anything after it won't work.

Comment: OH, you're supposed to do `ctx.author.roles`. Message is a string, not a discord.Message object

Comment: @12944qwerty Exactly! That is a silly mistake there. He is using the `event` thing in the `Command API`

Comment: @BhavyadeepYadav Yes, but that usage would still return an AttributeError. Unless OP used a handler, I'm not sure why it didn't send an error

Comment: Thanks!!!It's working now